# Regex to exclude URL with special configuration

Tags: php, regex

I want to exclude a `url` with this configuration `https://subdomain.example.com/y22la7hv` from a string.

I'm trying to do this with the following regex but is not working: `https://subdomain\.example\.com/([a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)+)`

Where am I failing?

Comment: Why shouldn't it match?

Comment: Please specify what character you're using to surround the regex, and what function you're using in PHP, to help consider ambiguities.

Comment: You can exclude it, but what should be a valid match? Should it always be `https://` ?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is after lot's of trying and error. Enjoy!

```
$str = 'https://subdomain.example.com/y22la7hv';
$pattern = '/https:\/\/subdomain\.example\.com\/([a-zA-Z]+([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+)+)/i';
$exclude_rgx = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
```